# Search $block->getData('configProvider') in form.mini.phtml returns null after upgrade to 2.3.6

Tags: magento2.3, blocks, di

In 2.3.6, the following line was added to form.mini.phtml:

`$configProvider = $block->getData('configProvider');`

Since the upgrade, this returns null and causes a fatal error due to this subsequent call on the null object:

`$configProvider->isSuggestionsAllowed()`

"**Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isSuggestionsAllowed() on null**"

My site uses a custom module that adds notices during shipping and checkout using blocks.  This module is causing the fatal error, but it shouldn't have anything to do with the search block.

I need to change the module di.xml file or custom class to return a configProvider for search, or tell it to use the default class.  Can anyone point me the right direction?   Many thanks.

Here is my code:

*/app/code/Port80/CIBC/etc/frontend/di.xml*

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="cms_block_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Port80\CIBC\Model\ConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type> 
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\Vat" type="Port80\CIBC\Model\Customer\Vat" />
</config>
```

*/app/code/Port80/CIBC/Model/ConfigProvider.php*

```
use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;

class ConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    /** @var LayoutInterface  */
    protected $_layout;

    public function __construct(LayoutInterface $layout)
    {
        $this->_layout = $layout;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return [
            'payment_notices' => $this->_layout->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('checkout_payment_notices')->toHtml(),
            'shipping_notices' => $this->_layout->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('checkout_shipping_notices')->toHtml()
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem after upgrading to 2.3.6. One of my theme layout files referred to the Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml template without the configProvider argument. adding the configProvider argument like this solved the issue:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configProvider" xsi:type="object">Magento\Search\ViewModel\ConfigProvider</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Comment: An additional note: The related "search_suggestion_enabled" config setting cannot be changed for the MySQL search provider in Magento CE, which means that search suggestions got disabled in my case... Solved by overriding the form.mini.phtml template from the Magento Search module

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up overriding form.mini.phtml too.

Comment: where to add this lines ?